# Making matrices in dart

Tags: dart

Ok guys, i've tried this:

```
List<num> test
for(num i = ...){
   test[i]...
   (...)
    for(num j = ...){
      test[i][j] = ...
    }
}
```

today but didn't seem to work. My question is... Is there a way to make this in Dart? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
main() {
  List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      list.add(j);
    }

    matrix.add(list);
  }

  print(matrix);
  print(matrix[2][4]);
}
```

If you know the length ahead of time, and it won't change, you can pass the length to the constructor:

```
main() {
  int size = 10;
  List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>(size);
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    List<int> list = new List<int>(size);

    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      list[j] = j;
    }

    matrix[i] = list;
  }

  print(matrix);
  print(matrix[2][4]);
}
```

Notice the main difference. In the first example, the list is created empty, so the loops need to explicitly add elements to the list. In the second example, the list is created with a fixed size, with null elements at each index.

**Changelog**: The original version of the second example used the `List.fixedLength(size)` constructor, which existed before Dart 1.0.

Comment: That was exactly the way i was doing, just wanted to know if there was another way, thanks ;)

Comment: I think the fixedLength named constructor dissapeared in the 1.0 release. You now just give the length as an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

One way to construct a list with a different value in each position is to use the idiom
`new Iterable.generate(size, function).toList()`

```
makeMatrix(rows, cols) =>
    new Iterable<List<num>>.generate(
        rows,
        (i) => new List<num>.fixedLength(cols, fill: 0)
      ).toList();

main() {
  print(makeMatrix(3, 5));
}
```

prints:  `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

It is slightly annoying that to get the `fill:` parameter you have to construct a fixed length list.  Without a fill value, the inner lists would contain `null`s.  One way to get an extendable list with an initial value is to create an empty list and grow it.

```
(i) => <num>[]..insertRange(0, cols, 0)
```

This is using a method cascade to modify the list before returning it - `a..b()..c()` calls `a.b()` and `a.c()` before returning `a`.  This is handy as it avoids the need for a temporary variable. 
Note that, for some reason, `insertRange` has a positional rather than a named `fill` parameter.

If you want more control over the contents, you can extend the generate-to-list idea to two levels:

```
makeMatrix(rows, cols, function) =>
    new Iterable<List<num>>.generate(
        rows,
        (i) => new Iterable<num>.generate(cols, (j) => function(i, j)).toList()
      ).toList();

main() {
  print(makeMatrix(3,5, (i, j) => i == j ? 1 : 0));
}
```

prints: `[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]`

Comment: This is an very interesting approach... There's any problem in generating the list with null values and then fill it with other values?

Answer (score 1):

There are some excellent libraries on [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/) for handling matrices (like Kevin Moore's BOT for example), but if your looking for something quick, you can just do:

```
List<List> test = new List<List>(n);
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  test[i] = new List(n);
}

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    test[i][j] = myValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be an interesting library to work for... I'm definitely taking a look, thanks ;)